# Adjusting time correctly using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8

I am creating an appointment app that has the capability to view monthly/weekly. The standard view, is able to show correct times in HH:mm, only between 9:00 - 17:00 . However, the monthly/weekly I can't convert and shows in full 24 hour time.

For the monthly I have:

```
public LocalTime getTime() {
         return time;
}

    @FXML
private void viewByMonthHandler(ActionEvent event) {
    
    DataProvider.getAppointmentsByMonth().clear();
    DataProvider.getAppointmentsByWeek().clear();
    
    if(viewByMonthRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            // I was using these two to try and convert
            //DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            //DateTimeFormatter timeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM HH:mm");

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(cal.getTime());

        DataProvider.setMonthlyView(month);
    }      
    
    sortAppointment();
    viewByComboBox.setItems(viewByMonth);
    
}
```

I have tried :

```
String month = new DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM HH:mm").format(cal.getTime());
```

and:

```
String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(timeFormat);
```

error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
```

for the weekly I have:

```
    @FXML
private void viewByWeekHandler(ActionEvent event) {
    
    DataProvider.getAppointmentsByMonth().clear();
    DataProvider.getAppointmentsByWeek().clear();
    
    if(viewByWeekRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        
        DataProvider.setWeeklyView(0);
    }
    
    sortAppointment();
    viewByComboBox.setItems(viewByWeek);

}
```

setWeeklyView:

```
    public static void setWeeklyView (int weekForReference) {
    
    try {
        
        ArrayList<Integer> selectedAppointmentsByWeek = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Statement statement = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet weeklyAppointments = statement.executeQuery("SELECT appointmentId from appointment where year(start) = YEAR(date_add(curdate(), interval " + weekForReference + " WEEK)) and weekofyear(start) = weekofyear(date_add(curdate(),interval " + weekForReference + " WEEK));");
        
        while(weeklyAppointments.next()) {
            selectedAppointmentsByWeek.add(weeklyAppointments.getInt(1));
            
        }
        
        for(int appointmentId : selectedAppointmentsByWeek) {
            
            ResultSet selectAppointment = statement.executeQuery("SELECT customer.customerName, customer.customerId, contact, title, type, location, description, start, end FROM appointment JOIN customer ON customer.customerId = appointment.customerId WHERE appointmentId =" + appointmentId);
            selectAppointment.next();
           
            
            Appointment appointment = new Appointment();
            
            String customerName = selectAppointment.getString(1);
            int customerId = selectAppointment.getInt(2);
            String contact = selectAppointment.getString(3);
            String title = selectAppointment.getString(4);
            String type = selectAppointment.getString(5);
            String location = selectAppointment.getString(6);
            String description = selectAppointment.getString(7);
            String start = selectAppointment.getString(8);
            String end = selectAppointment.getString(9);
            
            appointment.setCustomerName(customerName);
            appointment.setContact(contact);
            appointment.setTitle(title);
            appointment.setType(type);
            appointment.setLocation(location);
            appointment.setDescription(description);
            appointment.setStart(start);
            appointment.setEnd(end);
            appointmentsByWeek.add(appointment);
            
        }
        
    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    
}
```

The setMonthlyView is almost identical, just replacing weekly with monthly. How could I go about formatting these so they are no longer HH:mm:ss.S and in between 9:00-17:00? I have taken the advice previously given to me for the little parts, and still can't figure it out. Thank you so much for taking the time to read and help.

Answer (score 1):

Do one of these do what you want.

12 hour

```
String localDateTime12Hour =     
    LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM hh:mm a"));
System.out.println(localDateTime12Hour);
```

24 hour

```
String localDateTime24Hour =     
   LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM HH:mm"));
System.out.println(localDateTime24Hour);
```

Prints

```
July 06:11 PM
July 18:11
```

- Use `HH` for 24 hour
- Use `hh` for 12 hour (the `a` provides AM or PM)

Remember to use `LocalDateTime` and not `LocalTime` when specifying formatter attributes like `MMMM`.  You are returning a `LocalTime` object in your `getTime()` method.  And I would avoid using `Calendar` and `Date` as they are outmoded.  Use classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.